# SVN stopped working after server move/rename

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I use SVN with SSH using Subclipse in Eclipse. My repository resides on my hostgator server. Everyhting was working fine until hostgator decides to move the server to another place giving it and new server name and new IP.

Since then, whenever I try to commit or update I get the following error:

No Repository found in 'svn+ssh://username@domainname:2222/home/username/repo/appRepo/trunk/appname

offcourse where username and domainname and appname actual values are hidden from this question.

What on earth could be going wrong? It is still the same user name and domain name?!

EDIT:
 I found the main reason (I hope) but I dont know how to fix it so maybe someone can help. My path changed on the server from /home/username to /home4/username! Any idea how to fix that in eclipse/SVN so I go to home4 instead of home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are using `svn+ssh`. Following the IP address change, the SSH fingerprint would change too, so I am wondering if your ssh client denies access to the server and (confusingly) reports "No repository found"?

Check what happens if you execute `ssh domainname -l username`. Answer `yes` to changed fingerprint warning, then try to interact with svn again.

Comment: Thank you , I am able to get the new finger print as I get asked for that. But believe it or not  I think I figured the reason why but I dont know how to fix it. My path changed on the server from /home/username to /home4/username! Any idea how to fix that in eclipse/SVN?

Comment: But I use eclipse to connect. I dont want to change path of repo. I want to change the path that Eclipse uses to connect

Comment: I found it, I can use the relocate option in eclipse. Since you gave me the hint of the switch operation (no aware of it) then I will accept the answer